# How to call function from one function in traits (two function are present in parent traits)

Tags: php, function, functional-programming, call, traits

I define traits in php. i was try to communicate between two function witch are present in same traits, I got fatal error.

> ---------------------------error-------------------------------- 
>   Fatal error:  Call to undefined function crypto_rand_secure()
>   in
>   /var/www/html/clients/assuredo/include/config/generateToken/token.php
>   on line 28

I was try to call function `crypto_rand_secure()` in side the function `getToken()`.

```
trait token
    {
        public function crypto_rand_secure($min, $max)
            {
                $range = $max - $min;
                if ($range < 1) return $min; // not so random...
                $log = ceil(log($range, 2));
                $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
                $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
                $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
                do {
                    $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
                    $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
                } while ($rnd > $range);
                return $min + $rnd;
            }

    public function getToken($length)
        {
            $token = "";
            $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            $codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";
            $max = strlen($codeAlphabet); // edited

            for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $token .= $codeAlphabet[crypto_rand_secure(0, $max-1)];
            }

            return $token;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use unneccessary tagging - the whole question has no connection to "functional programming", and the tag `call` should not be used after all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual in all classes, you have to use `$this->` in front of a function name

Comment: $token .= $codeAlphabet[$this->crypto_rand_secure(0, $max-1)];

Comment: Yes, exactly - that should work. If not, you should share more details